# Merge together similar values in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code

```
select t_order.wh_id, t_order.bill_to_code, t_pick_detail.pick_area, count(*) as "OUC"
from t_order
INNER JOIN t_pick_detail on t_order.order_number = t_pick_detail.order_number
where t_order.wh_id = 'MP'
group by t_order.bill_to_code, t_pick_detail.pick_area, t_order.wh_id
```

Which Produces this

```
MP      GPS1       165
MP      GPS2       13
MP      GPS3       19
MP      BULK LIPS  128
MP      PICK FACE  19
MP             44
MP      CLS    3
```

Now what I need to add to the code is something that can merge the 3 "GPSn" rows into one called like "GPS" while not changing the "GPSn" permanently, while still displaying all of the other data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` in the `select` and `order by`:

```
select o.wh_id,
       (case when o.bill_to_code like 'GPS%' then 'GPS' else o.bill_to_code
        end) as bill_to_code,
       d.pick_area, count(*) as OUC
from t_order o INNER JOIN
     t_pick_detail d
     on o.order_number = d.order_number
where o.wh_id = 'MP'
group by o.wh_id,
         (case when o.bill_to_code like 'GPS%' then 'GPS' else o.bill_to_code
          end), d.pick_area;
```

EDIT:

You could try this `case` instead:

```
         (case when o.bill_to_code in ('GPS1', 'GPS2', 'GPS3') then 'GPS' else o.bill_to_code
          end)
```

However, the `like` should work.

Comment: It still doesn't merge those that that include GPS, results below;                                                                                                       MP  GPS3         19
MP  BULK LIPS 128
MP  PICK FACE 19
MP                    44
MP  GPS1         165
MP  GPS2          13
MP  CLS 3

Comment: @user3095083 . . . It should, if you remove `o.bill_to_code` from the `group by` and replace it with the `case` expression.

Comment: I copied the exact code you gave me above and got similar results which were the same, any ideas how I can update the code to make it work? thanks

Comment: Could there be other characters  in the code so `like 'GPS%'` doesn't match?

Comment: no it simply has GPS1,GPS2,GPS3 in the database and i would like these 3 to be merged into one cell called GPS when i run the code? any other ideas? thanks for your help so far though.

Comment: Those values should match `GPS%' and be replaced by `GPS` for aggregation purposes.

Comment: IT DOES WORK!! THANK YOU!!  it was checking for GPS in bill to code but needed it to be looking in pick area, my fault should have check that along time ago! thank you!